# NetBeans IDE no autocomplete due to JSX parsing error

Tags: javascript, netbeans-8, reactjs

I'm working with NetBeans 8.0.2 on a React project.

As NetBeans has no support for JSX, the file is interpreted as vanilla javascript and the whole JSX parts are marked as syntax errors.

The fact that all parts with JSX are marked as errors cause no problem for me, I can do with it. The problem is that it seems that theses errors prevent NetBeans from parsing the file and provide auto-completion. (Of course for him the file is completely invalid). The file navigator also become blank.

Having auto-completion is really a must-have for me, I can't work on the javascript parts of that file without it.

If I put the JSX as comment, the file becomes valid and autocomplete works as expected.

I'm working on a file *.jsx.js that is automatically compiled by the jsx watcher in the command-line.

Example file:

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var test = 'Hello';
        var other = test; // When editing this line there's no way to get
                          // "test" in the auto-complete list, nor anything
                          // else defined in this file
        return <div>{ 'Hello World' }</div>; // Signals the error
                  // "Expected an operator but found < return <div>{ 'etc...
                  // And when the JSX expands on many lines there is a big
                  // variety of errors, due to the inability to parse JSX
    }
});
```

Is there a way to allow the file to be parsed even with theses "errors" ? I'm thinking about a way to:

- Skip errors and parse the remaining of the file; or
- Set the JSX sections in a sort of "comment" (If the solution involve adding text before and after JSX there's no problem); or
- Use a js syntax hack to make NetBeans believe that it *is* a comment (Maybe something that will be erased by the jsx watcher during compile-time ?); or
- Use a js syntax that makes the error stay on a special scope, so it doesn't ruin the whole file; or
- Something else ?

I've found a there are ["custom comments" to provide code folding](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds), maybe there is a similar way to set a part as comment or to be skipped ?

I've searched for solutions to my "thinkings" above but without success. But I believe the answer can be a simple trick that works for JSX in general (made for another IDE ?), or one that applies to NetBeans, not necessary with javascript.

EDIT: I've found that jshint has `/*jshint ignore:start */` and `/*jshint ignore:end */` comments to ignore part of a file, that's exactly what I'd like to do inside NetBeans, but I still don't know if such a feature exists for the internal file parser.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/STRML/JSXHint/

Comment: @tkone I'm trying to modify the behaviour inside the IDE. I believe the tool you link to cannot replace NetBeans internal error parser ?

Comment: jshint is (was) a separate program netbeans uses to automatically lint your files as you type. You should be able to configure what it's using to do this (possibly through a plugin). Jshint iirc used to be a plugin itself.

Comment: If I can change this, I have no idea how to do it. And in my case the error not only prevent linting but also indexing variables/functions/etc...